# linking to nested JQuery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked at a series of related questions here, but given my extremely limited knowledge of JQuery have not been able to adapt the solutions to my code, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The basic problem is that I have tabs within tabs and linking only works if the tab is active. My understanding is the non-active tabs somehow need to be set to active through onclick behavior, but I have no idea how to accomplish this.

More specifically, how can I modify the links that exist elsewhere in the page to link to the sample code below?

Links I'm trying to get to work:

```
<p><a href="#spss1to1">Tab1</a></p>
<p style="padding-left: 30px;"><a href="#spss-inner-1to1">Tab1a</a></p>
<p style="padding-left: 30px;"><a href="#spss-left-1to1">Tab1b</a></p>
<p><a href="#spss1toMany">Tab2</a></p>
<p style="padding-left: 30px;"><a href="#spss-inner-1toMany">Tab2a</a></p>
<p style="padding-left: 30px;"><a href="#spss-left-1toMany">Tab2b</a></p>
```

Tabs:

```js
<!-- jQuery -->
<p><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" /></p>
<p>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(function() {
jQuery( "#tabstop" ).tabs();
jQuery( "#tabs1" ).tabs();
jQuery( "#tabs2" ).tabs();
});
// ]]></script>
</p>
<div id="tabstop">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#spss1to1">One-to-One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#spss1toMany">One-to-Many</a></li>
    </ul>
            <div id="spss1to1">
                <div id="tabs1">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#spss-inner-1to1">Tab1a</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#spss-left-1to1">Tab1b</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="spss-inner-1to1">
                        <p align="center">Tab1a text</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="spss-left-1to1">
                        <p align="center">Tab1b text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="spss1toMany">
                <div id="tabs2">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#spss-inner-1toMany">Tab2a</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#spss-left-1toMany">Tab2b</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="spss-inner-1toMany">
                        <p align="center">Tab2a text</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="spss-left-1toMany">
                        <p align="center">Tab2b text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? It seems to work fine. What is the *expected* behavior?

Comment: The tabs work, but I don't know how to link to them properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#o-tabs" ).tabs();
    $( "#i-tabs-1" ).tabs();
    $( "#i-tabs-2" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#TabLink1-1 a").click(function() {
            $( "#o-tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 0 );
            $( "#i-tabs-1" ).tabs( "option", "active", 0 );
        });

        $("#TabLink2-2 a").click(function() {
            $( "#o-tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
            $( "#i-tabs-2" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
        });

        $("#TabLink2-3 a").click(function() {
            $( "#o-tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
            $( "#i-tabs-2" ).tabs( "option", "active", 2 );
        });


    });

</script>


</head>
<body>

<!-- the links asked about in this question should take this form -->
<div id="TabLink1-1"><a href="#tab1-1">Tab 1-1</a></div>
<div id="TabLink2-2"><a href="#tab2-2">Tab 2-2</a></div>
<div id="TabLink2-3"><a href="#tab2-3">Tab 2-3</a></div>


<div id="o-tabs" class="tabs">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Tab one content.</p>
    <div id="i-tabs-1">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1-1">Tab 1-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1-2">Tab 1-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1-3">Tab 1-3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-1-1">
        <p>Tab one content.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-1-2">
        <p>tab two content.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-1-3">
        <p>tab three content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>tab two content.</p>
    <div id="i-tabs-2">
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2-1">Tab 2-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2-2">Tab 2-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2-3">Tab 2-3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-2-1">
        <p>Tab one content.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-2-2">
        <p>tab two content.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-2-3">
        <p>tab three content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>tab three content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```